# Jest: How to test for something inside of a callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

There is a static function in my react component which I want to test using jest.

```
static async getInitialProps (context, apolloClient) {
  const { req } = context
  const initProps = { user: {} }

  if (req && req.headers) {
    const cookies = req.headers.cookie
    if (typeof cookies === 'string') {
      const cookiesJSON = jsHttpCookie.parse(cookies)
      initProps.token = cookiesJSON['auth-token']
      if (cookiesJSON['auth-token']) {
        jwt.verify(cookiesJSON['auth-token'], secret, (error, decoded) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error)
          } else {
            redirect(context, '/')
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I got so far, which is testing for the call of `jwt.verify`. But how do I test for the callback of that?
I want to check for the call of `redirect`, if there is no error...

```
test('should call redirect', () => {
  // SETUP
  const context = { req: { headers: { cookie: 'string' } } }
  jsHttpCookie.parse = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({ 'auth-token': 'token' })
  jwt.verify = jest.fn(() => redirect)
  // EXECUTE
  Page.getInitialProps(context, {})
  // VERIFY
  expect(jwt.verify).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to explicitly declare your callback

```
const callback = (error, decoded) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error)
    } else {
        redirect(context, '/')
    }
}
```

and test it separatly.

Another option is to make a smarter mock for jwt.verify

```
jwt.verify = jest.fn((token, secret, callback) => callback())
```

This way your actual callback will be called and can be tested